# What's the difference between Microsoft Apps vs regular software?

Tags: windows-8

Being new to Windows 8, I'm confused by this simple question: how is the app different from a regular software (that we all know pre-Windows 8). For example, for VLC and Dropbox, I have both the app and the application.

What is the recommended practice regarding installing the app vs installing the software?

Comment: the apps are developed for being used by touch very easily. The old desktop application are not very good when you try to use them with touch.

Answer (score 0):

This is generally user preference.  Windows Metro (or at least the interface formerly known as metro) Apps are generally designed for touch and are built in a way that makes them very user friendly to those who either prefer not to, or cannot use a mouse.

Normally, a touch app will run full screen and you can use mouse or finger gestures to switch apps where a desktop app relies on clicking window to window, or Alt+Tab etc.

For the most part, they (store apps) will have all the functionality of the "Desktop" edition of the programs.  However, this is not always the case.

Examples of this include Windows Internet Explorer 11 (Which only has a subset of the "options menu" on the touch app), Skype (which only allows screen sharing on the desktop version) and various others.

The best advice is to try both and see which you prefer.

With the next windows release, there appears to be plans to allow a user to run a "touch app" within a window, so you will get the best of both worlds (in theory).

From a programmer’s perspective, there are also more languages available to use when generating desktop apps and scripts than there are for touch, but store apps leverage a lot of new technologies and are built on strong frameworks (which are also available when writing desktop apps)

I guess in a nutshell it comes down to whether you like the touch apps, whether you have a touch enabled device and which version of an app you prefer to use.